# app keeps stopping, but cannot find any problems

Tags: java, android

I want to debug my project, but it keeps stopping, I tried debugging it but cannot find any problems
code:

```
TextView colorTextView;
Button plumButton;
Button blueButton;
Button goldButton;
    
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );
    plumButton = findViewById(R.id.plumButton);         
    plumButton.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(v == plumButton){
                 colorTextView.setText( "Plum is a deep purple color. It is used in weedings. " );
            }
        }
    });
}
```

What's wrong in my code or I is it a bug in AVD?

Comment: Remove if(v == plumButton), this condition is not neccesary because the onClickListener is already tied to the plumButton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `onClickListener` of `plumButton`, your are trying to set text to `colorTextView`, but you have not initialised at-least not in above snippet.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );
    plumButton = findViewById(R.id.plumButton);
    colorTextView = findViewById(R.id.colorTextView); // add this line         
    plumButton.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(v == plumButton){
                 colorTextView.setText( "Plum is a deep purple color. It is used in weedings. " );
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: glad I could help, please accept if you think it solved your question.

Answer (score 0):

you must initialize textView you are trying to use

add this  line of code :

```
colorTextView = findViewById(R.id.colorTextView);
```